# A dumb question on L'Hospital rule

Tags: real-analysis

In my book I've found the rule of L'Hospital rule as:

1. If $f,g$ are diffentiable on $(c-\delta,c+\delta)-\{c\}$ and $g,g'\ne0$ on $(c-\delta,c+\delta)-\{c\}$ with $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\infty$ then $\lim_{x\to c}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l(\in\mathbb R^*)\implies\lim_{x\to c}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l.$
2. If $f,g$ are diffentiable on $(c,\infty)$ and $g,g'\ne0$ on $(c,\infty)$ with $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$ then $\lim_{x\to c}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l(\in\mathbb R^*)\implies\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l.$

But Bartle-Shebert text didn't consider the condition that $g$ need to be non-zero in $(c-\delta,c+\delta)-\{c\}$ (or $(c,\infty)$ respectively) to arrive at the same conclusion.

May I remove the nonzero condition of $g?$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but for uninteresting reasons, and you won't get much out of it.

If $g$ has only finitely many zeroes in $(c-\delta,c+\delta)\setminus\{c\}$ you can ignore them simply by using a smaller $\delta$.

On the other hand, if $g$ has zeroes arbitarily close to $c$, then due to the Mean Value Theorem, $g'$ will have zeroes arbitrarily close to $c$ too. Then $\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ won't exist, and the rule will tell you nothing anyway.